# What are the reasons for the rise in Euroscepticism over the last few years?

Tags: european-union

Eurosceptic political parties in Europe have been on the rise over the last few years. What are the reasons for this? What are the main arguments made by Eurosceptics against the EU?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/34618/do-nascent-exit-movements-currently-exist-within-the-eu/34620#34620

Comment: Did Euroscepticism actually rise, or did it rather become more visible in recent years?  That is an important distinction.

Comment: This might also be a very region specific perception question with more euroscepticism in some and less in other countries. Any particular region or country in mind regarding the question?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

## Taking Benefits for Granted

The last time I was to Belgium, we didn't actually stop in Belgium. We drove right through from the Netherlands to France. I'm old enough to remember having to stop at borders for long waiting lines.

Earlier this year a young colleague of mine decided to tour south-eastern Europe on his vacation. He went into a train to Vienna and by bus and train from there. No plan, just a backpack and a credit card. As he told it, he was **surprised** that in the train to Serbia people came and wanted to see his papers. He was glad that his national ID card was enough, because he had not thought to bring a passport. We had a good laugh at the office when he told the story.

## A Perception of EU Overreach

They thought they were getting into a free trade area, now the EU is regulating the shape of cucumbers, the power of lightbulbs, and refugee rights. What has that to do with free trade?

Well, people in some of the older EU member states have always seen the EU as a political project, with an **ever tighter integration**. Others just wanted [free movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Single_Market#Free_movement_of_persons) and [structural and cohesion funds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_Funds_and_Cohesion_Fund), with **no strings attached**. Nobody told them it doesn't work that way.

(Or rather, it could work that way if there was consensus. But if the net payers have different ideas from the net recipients, things get ugly.)

## A Perception of Demands for Bailouts

During the banking crisis, some EU/Eurozone members had to be funded by others. Among the stable and strong economies, there is a perception that some south-eastern members are profligate wastrels who want others to subsidize their laziness. This is not entirely accurate, of course.

- Industries in countries like Germany, France or the Netherlands benefit from the weaker Euro which would be grossly undervalued if it was just for those countries. Look what happened to the [Swiss Franc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss_franc#2011%E2%80%932014:_Big_movements_and_capping). The Euro is kept lower by the bad credit rating of some members.
- Biases enter this perception. Just compare the [Latvian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2008_Latvian_financial_crisis) financial crisis with the Greek one. Greece got much more blame.

## A Perception of a Lack of Democracy

While the EU parliament is elected by the people, the rest of the EU decisions are made by representatives of the member governments (who are elected by the people, either directly or indirectly). There are two or three steps between the popular vote and the EU commissioner. This lends itself to claims of missing democratic legitimation.

## Fear of Change in a Globalizing World

Things are changing. Fast. Think back 10 years and the iPhone was a novelty. Now we have selfies, emoticons, and uber. Amazon is replacing shops. Imagine what will happen when autonomous cars replace trucks and delivery vans. Quite a lot of people feel threatened by the pace of change.

Populists see the distant EU as a perfect **scapegoat** for all the problems. If something goes right, they take the credit. If something goes wrong, they had no choice, it was the EU. *Yeah, sure.*

Comment: This is a very German-centric view and the implicit account of the Euro crisis is simplistic.

Comment: Some improvement suggestions if you feel like you want to incorporate them: There is also the perception that the EU is undemocratic and bureaucratic with people attributing much power to EU bureaucrats. At Brexit we see that the EU is perceived as immigration friendly (wrt. members and non-members) meaning people that are anti immigration tend to be anti-EU. Similarly there might be a perception of lost independence with the EU courts to answer to in some matters. Finally I'd distinguish between particular EU-scepticism and Euroscepticism in general.

Comment: In the context of the "fear of change" it's also good to note that there are some indication that automation actually is causing more unemployment at the "bottom" of the market (that the rule of "automation causes new jobs" is holding up less and less over time) and that this causes more unhappiness that needs to be scapegoated. Immigration and secondarily the EU seem to be the favorite targets.

Comment: Regulating the shape of cucumbers and the power of lightbulbs actually has everything to do with free trade.  Refugee rights, not so much, but those derive from UN and CoE rights too.

Comment: I'd add "poor economic development" as a main factor as well. In general, the last decade (!) has been affected by high unemployment and stagnating wages. Certainly austerity measures have had their effects, but increased immigration has not helped. The EU is an easy target for anger - being the main obstacle for governments wanting to inflate their way out of the problem (Euro) and hinder movement of people (which goes against the 4 freedoms). Nevermind that inflating the problems away and barring borders is like pissing in your pants to keep warm. Works in the beginning.

Comment: @Relaxed, I thought a bit about your comment re a German viewpoint on the funding issues. The sentiment I reported is certainly common among German eurosceptics, but I believe it is *also* common in other northern/western net-payer countries. Perhaps a separate bullet point is missing for countries which believe that EU prevent them from necessary deficit spending / printing their way out of debt. (Which one it would be would only become clear in hindsight, of course, and it might depend on who writes the history book in question.)

Comment: @o.m. Another key part of the "Lack of Democracy/Representation" is that elected officials can only ever **vote** on a piece of legislation in the E.U.; while the unelected officials are the only ones who can *propose* legislation. Additionally, proposing similar legislation multiple times (such as Article 11 and 13) means even when it was shot down, it will get a *"re-roll"* meaning that policies that your state may be adamantly against will be enforced on you if they just keep re-rolling long enough.

Comment: This is less of an answer to explain why euroscepticism has risen, and more of a comment about how stupid you think eurosceptics are. Which is an opinion you are free to have, but it's not what the question really asked.

Comment: You mentioned the perception that countries with received bailouts were foolish with their money but there is another, and virtually opposite, perception among the euroskeptics (a weasel word if ever I heard one) that the evil EU is punishing them with their bailout terms and forcing austerity on them.  Ironically both sides, despite having opposite ideas, would appear to wish the bailouts after the 2008 crash never happened.

Comment: @EricNolan, the bailout terms are seen as unfair punishment by some of those facing austerity and as unearned generosity by some having to pay. One could almost say they must be doing something right to get outrage from both sides. :-)

Comment: Why do these posts seem to fail to notice that people might honestly just not WANT to work together with some others? A cultural dislike if you will?

Comment: @paul23, dislike of specific other countries is rarely given as a reason for euroscepticism. Many eurosceptics happily cooperate with eurosceptics from other countries.

Comment: On the politic level indeed: but on the actual "ground" when talking to people around here it is given as reason for support; "they're social system is simply imcompatible, they have to change their tax-paying-motivation before we should work with them". Is (for me) the most heard answer. (Though when I asked to write it down people said things differently since they don't like being called racist).

Answer (score 49):

**It hasn't risen much** (at least not EU-wide).

The Eurobarometer [Interactive search system](http://ec.europa.eu/COMMFrontOffice/PublicOpinion/index.cfm/Chart/index) allows users to create line trends of answers to survey questions over time.  One such question is:

> Taking everything into consideration, would you say that (your country) "has on balance benefited"/"would benefit" or not from being a member of the EU?
>   Taking everything into consideration, would you say that (your country) has on balance benefited or not from being a member of the European Union?
>   European Union (from 03/1983 to 05/2011)

[image: Eurobarometer trends]
*Source: [Eurobarometer](http://ec.europa.eu/commfrontoffice/publicopinion/index.cfm/Chart/getChart/chartType/lineChart//themeKy/4/groupKy/4/savFile/73)*

These data unfortunately end in 2011, but for a different question, data do extend to the end of 2017:

> In general, does the European Union conjure up for you a very positive, fairly positive, neutral, fairly negative, or very negative image?
>   European Union (from 04/2000 to 03/2018)

[image: Positive feeling?]

The data as visualised lack uncertainty bars, and to measure whether there is a statistically significant trend would take more work.  However, at first glance, there does not appear to be a strong trend in "has your country benefited".  The only partial trend that appears clearly visible, is the drop in the number of people who answer "Don't know" since 2000.

The "image" question does show  that between 2009 and 2012, there was a decrease in "fairly positive" from around 40% to around 30%, trending back to 35% between 2012 and 2017.  The trend for "fairly negative" is roughly opposite.  There appears there may also be some increase in answers for "Neutral", but it would take more in-depth statistical modelling to calculate the significance.

One other recent data point, not from Eurobarometer, is a [Dutch survey on Brexit and Nexit](https://www.noties.nl/v/get.php?a=peil.nl&s=weekpoll&f=2018-09-30+fes.pdf) (=Dutch exit), which states that in 2016, 43% of surveyed people supported a Dutch exit, whereas in 2018, this had dropped to 30%.  Among supporters of the Dutch Socialist Party (left-wing), support for exit dropped from 52% to 20%.  Only among the populist right supporters is there still a (large) majority for Nexit.  Support for populist (far) right (nationalist/conservative) eurosceptic parties overall in The Netherlands have been mostly constant (with many ups and downs) in the past 16 years (Pim Fortuyn, Geert Wilders, Thierry Baudet).

Some graphs for specific countries:

Sweden, a clear increase in support for the EU:

[image: Sweden]

Greece, a clear decrease in support for the EU:

[image: Greece]

I would speculate that the Greek drop in support is due to the [Greek government-debt crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_government-debt_crisis).

Hungary, a dip in 2012 (Eurozone debt crisis) and a smaller dip in 2015 (European migrant crisis), but clear recovery in positive feelings since then, back to pre-dip levels:

[image: Hungary]

**Conclusion**: From available data, there does not appear to be much evidence for a large EU-wide trend in feelings about the EU, either pragmatically (whether it benefits the member state) or emotionally.  Overall EU trends *may* mask trends in specific countries, and there may be other trends not visible in the data as presented either.  The trends differ from country to country, and for those countries where there is a clear rise (such as Greece) the answers are likely specific to factors affecting that country.

**Discussion**: Clearly, there is a perception that euroscepticism has increased, more than it actually has.  Where is this perception coming from?  I would speculate (but have no evidence) that with the rise of populist right parties in some European (and non-European) countries in the past 20 years, eurosceptics in continental Europe have become more vocal (I believe they always have been vocal in England), people are more willing to speak their opinion when it is not aligned to the establishment.  With the rise of such parties, eurosceptics have received a voice in national parliaments and the European Parliament, and, more than before, in the mainstream media.

Comment: One could argue that the chart shows that UE 'benefit for your country'-rate has declined by about 8 points between 2006 and 2011 (Granted, 2006 is cherry-picking). More to the point, it is a pity that more recent data is not included, since most of the alleged decline in UE popularity comes after 2011 (populists and anti-UE politicians being successful in Austria, Hungary, Poland, Italy, UK, and to a lesser extend Denmark, Slovakia, Holland, Belgium, France or Greece)

Comment: @Evargalo I agree that this is a pity, and I don't know why these data are missing.  For what it's worth, I've cited at least one survey showing that for The Netherlands, there is a very clear drop in support for a Dutch exit in the past 2 years, in particular among left-leaning voters.

Comment: @Evargalo I've found some more recent data for a different question, and my conclusion remains, there is no evidence from this data for a clear overall trend in Euroscepticism.

Comment: In other words, people are about as skeptical about the EU as they used to be - the only real difference is that there are finally some political parties that represent this *full third of a population* (according to your first graph from Eurobarometer). Regardless of whether you're pro- or anti-EU, this is a good development for democratic societies. Of course, it's pretty likely the overlap between the actual political programs of those parties and what people actually want is about as good as for any other party :P

Comment: @Luaan That is a possible interpretation. When the political class has different views from the people overall, the cynical interpretation is that the politicians are out of touch, a (perhaps naively) optimistic interpretation may be that the political class are better informed and the people are wrong. Both can be true, the reality probably lies somewhere in-between.

Comment: Is a poll run by the EU the best sort of way to get at EU sentiment? Could you get a shy Euroskeptic effect? (I don't live in Europe, no idea how the Eurobarometer works)

Comment: @AzorAhai I don't see why it can't be, but even *if* it has a pro-EU bias (which I see no evidence of), we may still be able to trust trends, unless we would have reasons to believe such biases are themselves changing over time, which I don't think we have.

Answer (score 23):

I want to add one important point that I believe is a key factor especially in the **perception**, and that is what in Germany is called "über Bande spielen", maybe best translated as "indirect play". It's a political trick that has become more common in the last decade or so.

Basically, any political measure that the ruling party wants, but that is unpopular and would negatively impact the next election is instead brought forth on the EU level, discussed and made into an EU regulation. Then when it comes to the national level to be implemented into law, they put on a show of reluctance and fighting against it but ultimately (insert imagined *sigh*) they are force to do it by the evil EU.

Measures with a positive image are, of course, introduced locally with a big show of "look what good we are doing".

This way, a lot of what is perceived as negative apparently comes from the EU, and very little positive. This trick has become common and some journalists have uncovered endless cases where sometimes the same politicians championed a bill on the EU level and very publicly, valiently and *sigh* ultimately heroically fruitlessly **fought against** the same bill on the national level. But this case of political schizophrenia rarely enters the mainstream media and public memory.

This way the EU is made the scapegoat for many, many unpopular measures that actually did not originate at the EU level, while popular measures, even if they do originate with the EU, are celebrated as national government success stories.

Comment: This sounds like a very interesting theory, but is it true?  Do you have evidence to support it?

Comment: And if it is true, it's yet another reason why EU isn't a good thing - it further strengthens the "bureaucracy rather than democracy" argument, as well as shows the *real* power EU has compared to individual governments and political parties. If you can push legislature that wouldn't be approved locally onto the EU which allows you to push it locally, you've got quite a big problem, regardless of whether it's just political posturing or not.

Comment: I think there is some truth in this, and part of the reason is that EU politics is very invisible: very little TV time, for example, is given to interviews with senior EU politicians. Therefore they very rarely have to defend their policies in public. I assume that the reason they don't care much about TV coverage is that it has very little effect on whether they get re-elected, because few of them are elected directly by the public.

Comment: @gerrit - I do not have a study of media, but I'm actively following politics and I live in the heart of Europe, so unless my perception is dramatically tilted...

Comment: @MichaelKay The only place you can see EU politicians is usually in recordings from the proceedings - and those are pretty sad, with most of the seats empty at pretty much all times, people looking utterly bored the whole time, and no response to people raising any concerns whatsoever (other than the occasional smug smirk). Not surprising they're used quite frequently by the eurosceptic parties :) As for marketing, indeed, they don't care about public opinion at all, which again is part of the "bureaucracy rather than democracy" argument.

Comment: Upvoted for the part where the EU is used as a scape-goat for many uncomfortable political items.  If the boogieman is the reason for all these nasty things that happened in the past, who would be in favour of him?  Only those that blame the unpopular things they want to do on him.

Answer (score 18):

Because EU membership was sold to people with two very important promises:
1. There would be less regulation and bureaucracy, more freedom
2. The sovereignty of nations would not be infringed upon. Nations would not be forced to do things they did not agree upon first.

Both were boken. Badly.
There are a LOT of regulations coming from the EU (as a governing body), leading to increased costs and hurdles in most if not all areas of life. And while there are areas where it did lead to decreased regulations and costs, for a lot of people the net balance is negative. One good example where i live are people who used to do small scale, often part time farming. They used to be able to sell their crops and animals to local large scale food manufacturing companies for a good price. This money was either a considerable chunk or all of their income. But with EU regulations on farming, especially the raising of animals, the costs became too much for a lot of these small scale farmers and they either had to completely abandon farming or were relegated to selling only to private individuals, under the table, for a lot less money. This has hurt a lot of people in my country, most of them being in the poorer, rural areas. Also, as it turned out, a surprisingly large percentage of our national agricultural output came from these small farmers, and losing that did not go over well with people.

As for the second part. The obvious example is the handling of the migrant issue, and the migrant quotas that some countries tried to impose on others through EU laws. That is viewed (rightfully so IMHO) as a gross violation of the sovereignty of the individual nations. There are already a lot of issues with how some national and EU politicians are pushing for more and more centralisation of power in Brussels, against the will of a lot of the people in the EU, and the political ideologies they are pushing/forcing on people with said powers. But the handling of the migrant crisis is viewed by a lot of people as a critical crossroad. For them the outcome of it will decide whether the EU can be made to work or if it needs to be abandoned.

Comment: Welcome on politics.SE. Can you provide some links to demonstrate that those two promises were made for countries creating or joining the EU? AFAIK, the main objectives and promises of EU were peace, stability, and prosperity...

Comment: When did your country became a part of the EU? Because I do not know up to 1986, but before the incorporation of the Eastern Europe countries bureaucracy was already a criticism of the EU (of course, many times it was the case of people asking for EU funds complaining about how much paperwork to get money...)

Comment: Wasn't sold to me that way, if anything then the opposite. But, I rather find that the EU wasn't properly sold at all, there is no clear common message from the EU about what the EU should be towards the general populace and different national leaders "sell" it differently.

Answer (score 7):

This is a typical case of inadequation between the expected benefits and the perceived ones.

The topic is complex, and an in-depth explanation of it would probably not suited for the scope of this site. However, some elements might help you grasp an idea.

#### Conflicting Goals

The problem when you do a revolution, is that you typically agree that the guy who's there is bad. You all work together to get rid of him. But once that's done, you often fight amongst yourselves, because you never took time to find a system for afterwards. The French revolution, or even Lybian revolution (for something more recent) come to mind.

The EU has a bit of the same issue. With 3 "large" wars in 80 years (Prussia-France followed by the two World Wars), involving progressively more people and killing exponentially more people each time, both the leaders and the people of European countries felt like something should be done. But what?

People often expect the EU to spread humanist views, favour human rights, environment, peace, etc. So we would all be living better, to make sure that will share the best standards in Europe. We all live in peace, like each others, so we won't be waging wars again.

Some others, and among them many industry or polical leaders, are more focused on the economy. A shared market, leads to a shared economy, increased inter-dependence, and thus impossibility to do any total wars. And making some profit on the way won't harm much.

From the very beginning, the EU has been a ship trying to compromise between those approaches. The 1957 Rome Treaty claimed to be adressing the former, whereas the first actual agreement, merged the coal market.

During the Cold War, the EU was building and expanding itself, but partly as a way to protect itself from the USSR as well as keeping some independence from the USA. The USSR disappeared, the memory of the World Wars faded, people started to evaluate what they had built.

Many feel that the EU is too administrative, and restraints the free exchange and market. Others that the EU is too business oriented and not doing enough for the Human Rights, Environment, and general protection of the population.

#### Complexity

To put it simply, the EU has three institutions:

- the Parliament
- the European Court
- the Commission

The Parliament is directly elected by the European people. People can somewhat understand that, as it is quite common in the national systems as well. It holds legislative power.

The Court is somewhat separated, but holds judicial power. This entity often exists in one form or another in each country.

The commission is a complex and puzzling entity. It holds both executive and legislative power (often avoided in separate countries). It is composed for a part of the representants of each member countries, for a part of nominated people.

That complexity makes it hard to follow who takes which decision and who should be held responsible for each new rule. And that puzzles voters.

#### Communication issues

There is a huge communication issue for the EU. Except in very rare cases, the EU does not promote itself so much.

Whenever there is a debate on national politics, you would see representatives of both sides in all news medias: radio, TV, press, etc.

But you would rarely see the same thing whenever there is some debate at the European level. We French people regularly get to hear Muscovici (current European Commissioner for Economic and Financial Affairs, Taxation and Customs) in the media, but most of the time he is being asked about national politics rather than European ones.

I don't know if it's a question of consumer's interests, journalists, or EU officials, but the result is that for a large portion of the population, the EU institution looks like a black box, completely separated from "normal" people.

Even national politicians communicate European decisions sparingly and only to achieve national goals.

#### Populism and xenophobia

More or less latent since the 1970s, we live in a continuous "crisis". That crisis has many facets: economics, moral, societal, technological, etc. The economics part of it exploded since 2007.

People are by nature resistant to changes, and thus somewhat preoccupied about the future. And whenever we are in a crisis (or simply perceived to be in), we tend to look for culprits. Jews for example, have often been considered culprit (Geman's loss at the end of WWI, a few economic crises in the Holy Roman German Empire, etc.). It tends to unite a population against the culprit.

This is something often used by extremist parties. The rise of populism isn't something specific of Europe. The famous "Make America Great Again" of Trump is a clear illustration. The crisis is due, for some people (or presented as such), to the globalization, world economy and multinational firms. These are many heads, and hard to focus the hatred against. In Europe, the EU institutions are an embodiement of those. So by focusing the distrust and hate against the EU, those parties capitalize on the fear of many people.

Comment: You forgot the *European Council* and the *European Central Bank*.

Comment: @burrito77 the USA's political landscape is quite different from the European one. But the preference for nationals, getting out of international treaties as well as appealing to a "greater past", is a constant of many politicians and parties on the extreme right.

Comment: @burrito77 indeed. [They](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pat_Buchanan) aren't [that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jim_Gilchrist) hard to [find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Gaffney).

Comment: @burrito77, not sure I get what your issue is. Trump's policy does fit what I mentioned above, and as such can be compared to extreme-right politicians here in Europe or in other places. I could use more obscure references, but Trump's motto from the 2016 Presidential Election is quite well known and illustrate my point.

Comment: I have a few downvotes. Normally, I'd discard it as "hater gonna hate" thing... but reading Burrito77's comments (which disappeared), I'm now wondering whether I get them just by mentioning Trump?

Comment: In the same trend fits the "Swiss sovereignty referendum", which was recently [defeated](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-46335918) (fortunately so, IMO).

Comment: I upvoted this as I feel the lack of communication and publication from the EU bodies is a significant part.  If you visit an area of less advantageous economic means you will see EU funded projects with a few posters and so on.  This gives you a +1 for the EU advert.  If you live anywhere that does not get this project you see nothing about the EU appart from what turns up in headline news and is less positive.  For much of my life (mid-30s UK citizen based in south-east (not London)) most of what I heard about the EU was negative.

Comment: @TafT Wales has lots of EU funded infrastructure yet voted to leave, London has none (I think) yet voted to remain, so it's not as simple as that.

Comment: @gerrit That is a good point. Looking at https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-36616028 suggests we should form London, Scotland and Northern Island into a unit that remains in the EU to best fit the maps! Perhaps positive rhetoric is of little importance after all.

Comment: I remember reading an ad in Liverpool a few years ago stating that the work being done could only be done thanks to the EU. I've seen similar things in Poland. Surprisingly none in Germany or France. Or maybe I did not notice. At least not on that large fonts. However a few good words might be drown in a sea of bad ones. So the key is probably the radio, more than the amount of positive ads.

Answer (score 3):

I can only speak from the British perspective.  I don't feel that euroscepticism has risen at all in this country.  Throughout my lifetime it has seemed that among our politicians roughly half were in favour of EU membership, and half were against.  I don't think that has changed.

Most ordinary British people don't care whether we're in the EU or not.  But there are things they *do* care about, such as healthcare, job-security, etc.

The (evil?) genius of the Leave campaign was to draw a link in the public mind between our EU-membership and the things people care about... "You are worried about immigration?  That's the EU's fault.  You feel poor?  That's the EU's fault.  You want a better-funded health service?  Let's use the money we give to the EU.  etc."

The Remain campaign could have done something similar but they did not.

Of course, none of those statements is provably true or false.  Where there's certainty, there's no room for politics.

I think that idea: "they don't care about my objective so I'll just link my objective to what they do care about" might be a relatively new one in the world of politics.  I'm not aware of another example in British politics anyway - perhaps somebody here can correct me?

Comment: So we can prepare for a few more Brexins and Brexits in the following year as the (tight) majority fluctuates.

Comment: They were blaming those on the EU long before there was an active referendum campaign, though.  The EU even had/has a blog dedicated to debunking EU myths claimed in UK press.

Answer (score -1):

What made Europe rule the world? Institutional competition. Any time a scientist, businessman, inventor, artist or similar fell out with the ruling king, there was always another country where he was welcome. EU is killing all that (by coincidence, two non-EU countries in Europe, Switzerland and Norway, are among the richest countries in Europe) competition, making Europe stagnant and losing its influence (yes, Hitler is also a culprit).

Europe should be grateful that the Roman Empire fell, otherwise Europe might have developed like China och India - that is, much slower than what actually happened.

Yes, free trade is good but that is a unilateral thing. Just open your borders for import and if the taxpayers in another country wants to subsidize your consumption - just be grateful for their generosity.

Comment: Stating that Switzerland and Norway are rich because they are not in the EU is very misleading. Especially for Norway that is basically following EU rules without being part of the decision making. But it is one point brought up by eurosceptics. Soooo, good answer!(?)

Comment: How is it misleading? My point is that EU puts a dead cold hand on economic dynamics. Norway and Switzerland don't suffer from that hand, even if they, especially Norway, follows a lot of what EU decides.

Comment: Well now, if there exist subsidies, then I argue the "free" trade is not really free - some people are forced to pay for stuff they don't want.

Why are there subsidies anyway?

Comment: @d-b Albania and Transnistria are also not in the EU.  And Norway is pretty much half if not more than half in the EU anyway.

Comment: A much better case can be made that Norway and Switzerland are not in the EU because they are rich, which makes joining the EU financially less attractive and gives them the power to strike reasonable trade deals with the EU.

Comment: @gerrit So what? They are in the good half, the EFTA half.

Comment: @d-b I'm sure UK EFTA membership has far more support among pro-Remain people than among pro-Leave people, some of whom call joining EFTA "not really leaving" (staying in ESM and EUCU).  EFTA membership means respecting the Four Freedoms and respecting CJEU rulings, both of which the UK government has ruled out. It does allow to retain membership in Erasmus exchange or Horizon Europe, both of which the UK government has desired. The UK already had opt-outs for Eurozone and Schengen, making the difference with EFTA even smaller.  Apart from, of course, not having a say in ESM rules.

Comment: @d-b Are you sure you are trying to answer the OP's question at all? The first part of your answer pretty much has nothing to do with the question at all! The second part is so funny which you are referring to fall of the Roman Empire (perhaps you mean fall of the Western Roman Empire), which again is just a funny sentence without any relevance to the question. Finally, the third part of your answer... pretty much the same as its first part... BTW I don't wanna waste a point, besides my time that I spent to read your answer and write this comment, to downvote your answer...

Comment: @AloneProgrammer The Eastern Roman Empire also fell, and, long before that happened, became irrelevant. Are you American?